# Python - Input() multiple file paths at once and append in a list

Tags: python, list, zip

I am writing a code to zipFile multiple files based on user's input.
For example, user type couple file paths such as C:\Users\AAA\BBB, C:\Users\AAA\CCC,... The program will back up all these files into one single new zipFile.

Right now I'm using a loop (the code from "While True") and it works. But this only allows us to enter one path each time. Is there a neat way that we can input all the path at once and add each of them in a list (fileList here)?

And as I just started Python and I wrote it based on "A Byte of Python", I feel my code is kind of lengthy... Please feel free to provide recommendation to improve it. Thank you.

```
import os,time,zipfile

def createZip():

#  Define the file path to save the file
savePath=input('Enter file save path-->')
if len(savePath)==0:
    print('No path is found. Backup ends.')
#  Define the file to be saved
else:
    assert os.path.exists(savePath),"File path does not exist. Backup fails."  #  assert expression1, expression2, equals to if not expression1, raise AssertionError(expression2)

    fileList=[]
    while True:
        filePath=input('Enter files to save. Enter "Done" to end.-->')
        if filePath=='Done':
            break
        else:
            if len(filePath)==0:
                print('No path is found. Please enter files to save.')
            else:
                assert os.path.exists(filePath),"File path does not exist. Backup fails."
                fileList.append(filePath)

    today=savePath+os.sep+time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    now=time.strftime('%H%M%S')
    if not os.path.exists(today):
        os.mkdir(today)
        print('Successfully created directory', today)

    comment=input('Enter a comment -->')
    if len(comment)==0:
        target=today+os.sep+now+'.zip'
    else:
        target=today+os.sep+now+'_'+comment+'.zip'


    newZip=zipfile.ZipFile(target,'w',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)  #  'w' means write only; 'r' means read only
    for fName in fileList:
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(fName):
            for file in files:
                newZip.write(os.path.join(root,file))
    newZip.close()
    print('backup to',target)
```

createZip()

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly easy. You can split the text the user enters, but you need to worry about files with spaces in their names. The `shlex` lets you split a line the same way a unix-like shell would, which gives you the rules you need.

import shlex

```
fileList = []
while True:
    filePaths = input('Enter files to save. Enter "Done" to end.-->')
    if filePaths.lower() == "done":
        break
    for filePath in shlex.split(filePaths):
        if not os.path.exists(filePath):
            print("'{}' not found".format(filePath))
        else:
            fileList.append(filePath)
```

Comment: Does this not still ask the user for one path at a time?

Comment: @pstatix - it asks for "files to save" and if the user enters multiple file names separated by spaces - like you would in a shell - it will split them out.

Comment: Sure, separated by spaces. Didn't sound like the OP wanted a massive string of space delimited paths; hence my confusion.

Comment: @pstatix OP asked _Is there a neat way that we can input all the path at once_ ... You'll need some sort of separator and I figure a space will do.